# How to replace wp-admin with any text from wordpress admin URL?

Tags: wordpress

What is the easiest way to replace wp admin from wordpress admin URL?

Basically I want to change `http://localhost/wpsite/wp-admin`
with `http://localhost/wpsite/myadminpanel`.

Comment: get a security plugin which will help u do that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [support page](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9809/2187/how-to-change-your-wordpress-admin-url) for one hosting provider, which suggests installing one of the plugins below to achieve this:

- [Lockdown WP Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lockdown-wp-admin/) (this one seems a bit old now)
- [iThemes Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/)

And don't forget **make a full backup** of your website, before doing any of the changes!.

Comment: I am unable to find this setting in iThemes Security anymore. It seems that since they've changed the UI it's buried somewhere in the settings... Anyone knows where the setting can be found?

Comment: Actually I found it, right at the bottom of the Global Settings is an option to 'Hide Backend'

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using this plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/) and for me it work fine and it is very easy to setup